# ASP.NET 2.0: Problem in Httpcontext.current.session.add()

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

Can anybody help me to find out solution of following problem.

1. In ASP.NET website: at Application_OnPostAuthenticate() event, whatever code i write is executed for every request. therefore due to this customidentity object, countryid and weatherid is called everytime for each request (call for database for value). It effect response time of page and unneccessary code execute.

   void Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   ```
   // Get a reference to the current User

   IPrincipal objIPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;

   // If we are dealing with an authenticated forms authentication request

   if ((objIPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated) && (objIPrincipal.Identity.AuthenticationType == "Forms"))
   {
       CustomPrincipal objCustomPrincipal = new CustomPrincipal();
       objCustomPrincipal = objCustomPrincipal.GetCustomPrincipalObject(objIPrincipal.Identity.Name);
       HttpContext.Current.User = objCustomPrincipal;
       CustomIdentity ci = (CustomIdentity)objCustomPrincipal.Identity;            
       HttpContext.Current.Cache["CountryID"] = FatchMasterInfo.GetCountryID(ci.CultureId);
       HttpContext.Current.Cache["WeatherLocationID"] = FatchMasterInfo.GetWeatherLocationId(ci.UserId);
       Thread.CurrentPrincipal = objCustomPrincipal;
   }
   ```

   }

To solve this problem when i try tochange code as follows
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("test", FatchMasterInfo.GetWeatherLocationId(ci.UserId);); in place of cache i found foolowing error
"Object refrence not set to the instance of object"

I don't know whether we can store session variable inside Application_OnPostAuthenticate() event or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try doing this a bit later in the request, such as in the `PreRequestHandlerExecute` event:

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IPrincipal objIPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
    if ((objIPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated) && (objIPrincipal.Identity.AuthenticationType == "Forms"))
    {
        HttpSessionState session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
        CustomPrincipal objCustomPrincipal = new CustomPrincipal();
        if (session[objIPrincipal.Identity.Name] == null)
        {
            // get data from database or wherever
            objCustomPrincipal = objCustomPrincipal.GetCustomPrincipalObject(objIPrincipal.Identity.Name);
            CustomIdentity ci = (CustomIdentity)objCustomPrincipal.Identity;
            Object countryID = FatchMasterInfo.GetCountryID(ci.CultureId);
            Object weatherLocationID = FatchMasterInfo.GetWeatherLocationId(ci.UserId);
            // save in session (not cache as cache is application-wide, not per-user):
            session.Add(objIPrincipal.Identity.Name, objCustomPrincipal);
            session.Add(objIPrincipal.Identity.Name + "_CountryID", countryID);
            session.Add(objIPrincipal.Identity.Name + "_WeatherLocationID", weatherLocationID);
        }
        else
        {
            // already have custom principal object in session
            objCustomPrincipal = (CustomPrincipal)session[objIPrincipal.Identity.Name];
        }

        // set the custom principal object to context/thread
        HttpContext.Current.User = objCustomPrincipal;
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = objCustomPrincipal;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ironsam, Thank you very much. I have few more queries about the same 
1. By using GetCustomPrincipalObject() i am fetching roles and permissions of loggedin user. Its good practice for finding roles and permission here or we need to change code and place it somewhere else.
2. Why sessionstart event is not right place for session.add() ? 

Meanwhile i am implementing the solution you provided. I hope it will soleve the issue.

Comment: Edit:  @ironsam, I have tried the solution you provide. 
when i am fetching user at aspx page using following code

 CustomIdentity ci = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as CustomIdentity;

The value of ci comes null. 

I am not getting what wrong i did?

Comment: You should be able to get the CustomIdentity from the session object if you need to on the aspx page: 

CustomPrincipal pi = (CustomPrincipal)session[objIPrincipal.Identity.Name];

CustomIdentity ci = (CustomIdentity)pi.Identity;

As for best practices and when certain events occur in a request, this might help <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx>.

Comment: hi, Can you please explain me that if we have custom identity and principle in my Httpcontext then Is it good to fetch it from session? yes We can fetch it from both session and httpcontext . But what should we use?

Comment: I think it would be better to just get it from HttpContext, but if the custom one you set it isn't available right away in the remaining lifecycle of the request (likely having something to do with when you set it, in this case the PreRequestHandlerExecute event), then just go with the session one, if possible.

Comment: Hi ironsam, I tried your solution it really helps me. But you know when we request some aspx page then sometime it show error message for session. "object refrence not set to the instance of object".
Then i modify code as following
1. Add following if codition at line no 2
if ((objIPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated) && (objIPrincipal.Identity.AuthenticationType == "Forms"))
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
            {
2. Change session as Session at following code [s would be in capital case]
Session[objIPrincipal.Identity.Name]
Please acknowledge

Comment: If I understand, you are adding a condition to check and see if HttpContext.Current.Session != null before checking to see if the CustomPrincipal object is in there or not.  I think this would work, but hard to tell without seeing the rest of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to access the session in any event that happens in every request. Some requests don't even have session (for instance, a lot of web service calls, or calls to WebResource.axd that load static resources).

Answer (score 1):

Before adding value to cache object, check if it already exists in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have session state enabled. Does it work anywhere else (like in a web form's display)?

Look for a `<sessionState>` element under your system.web element in web.config make sure it's turned on (set it to InProc unless you have a web farm).